# Define and ActionListener in class which extends Button

Tags: java, swing

How to place Action Listener directly in definition of class that extends `Button` ?

If object of class `Button` is created then we could simply use anonumous inner class :

```
b = new Button("Click me");
b.addActionListener(
                    new ActionListener(){
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                            System.out.println("stringToPrint");
                        }
                    }
                );

how to do the same in below :
class CustomizedButton extends Button{
   String customClass;

   Button(String stringToPrint){
      super(customClass); //customClass is also button name
      this customString = stringToPrint;
   }

   /*this.addActionListener( //don't work this way
       new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                System.out.println(customClass);//use outer(?) field
            }
        }
     );*/
}
```

I need to create 20 almost identical but slightly different buttons, so anonymous inner is too long

Comment: Why can't you use a lambda and then a function in the class in which `b` is created?

Comment: Please tell us in a bit of detail what these buttons are to be used for.  Also, why do you state that an anonymous inner is "too long"? As per my example below, it can be one line, off-loading much of its functioning to a method.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels its really about object which inherits from JMenuItem and sets size of font in editor to given size, I've asked about Button, because its more popular object let to say

Comment: Please [edit] your question with this information, but also with more information -- the details. Note that if you're desiring JMenuItems and JButtons both sharing the same actions, then you can (again) use AbstractAction, and set the menu item and the button with the same Action. It's a very flexible and powerful way to do this. This way you can also enable and disable the similar menu items and buttons, since by disabling the shared Action, both components become disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare a private nested class, like so:

```
public class CustomizedButton extends Button{
    String customClass;

    CustomizedButton(String stringToPrint){
        super(customClass); //customClass is also button name
        this.customString = stringToPrint;
        addActionListener(new MyListener());
    }

    private class MyListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO: listener code here
        }
    }
}
```

But it's not much different from using an anonymous inner class or lambda:

```
public class CustomizedButton extends Button{
    String customClass;

    CustomizedButton(String stringToPrint){
        super(customClass); //customClass is also button name
        this.customString = stringToPrint;
        addActionListener(e -> myListenerCode(e));
    }

    private void myListenerCode(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO: listener code here
    }

}
```

Having said this, other issues come to mind:

- Usually it's best to favor composition over inheritance. I would bet that what you *really* want is some sort of factory method that creates your button complete with listener
- Why use AWT components such as the java.awt.Button class when it is 20+ yrs out of date? Why not Swing JButtons instead?
- If you were using Swing JButtons, best would be to create a custom Action rather than extend JButton. Actions can hold and change many button properties, including a listener, the displayed text, icons, the tool tip text (displayed on hover)....
- For that matter, you should favor JavaFX if this is a new project, since this is the current best-supported Java GUI library.

For example an AbstractAction class could look something like:

```
public class CustomizedAction extends AbstractAction{
    String text;

    CustomizedAction(String text, int mnemonic){
        super(text); //text is also button name
        this.text = text;
        putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic); // for alt-key short cut if desired
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String currentName = getValue(NAME); // same value as the text field
        System.out.println(currentName);

        // TODO: more listener code here
    }

}
```

and could be used like so:

```
JButton button = new JButton(new CustomizedAction("Foo", KeyEvent.VK_F));
```